# CentOS 7: VirtualBox is complaining that the kernel module is not loaded

Tags: virtualbox, centos7, kernel-module

**Background**:

I created a **sandbox** VM with VirtualBox on my macOS. It correctly spins up a VM (with CentOS7 running on it) on which I can access to.

**Inside this sandbox vm**, I want to spin up several vms in order to test Ansible Playbooks with Kitchen CI & Vagrant, thus I installed VirtualBox by downloading it from the following link: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.2.8/VirtualBox-5.2-5.2.8_121009_el7-1.x86_64.rpm

After the installation I executed the command:

`[david@vmkitchen-env ansible-test]# VBoxManage --version`

It returned:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module
         available for the current kernel (3.10.0-693.2.1.el7.x86_64) or it 
         failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it 
         by
           sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

         You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
5.2.8r121009
```

I installed the **Development tools**, but I keep getting the same issue.

I don't think I need to recompile any kernel module. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, after searching on the internet, and not just on the VirtualBox website, I found the solution, and I was right: I did not need to compile any module.
The following is the reference to the CentOS wiki page:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox

In a few words, I had to install `dkms` and `kernel-devel` packages. In order to do so, I needed to install EPEL repository; but personally I prefer to install and enable the IUS repository.

The following are the set of commands that worked for me:

`yum groupinstall "Development tools"`

`yum install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm`

`yum install dkms`

`yum install kernel-devel`

`reboot`

After the machine had rebooted, I was able to get VirtualBox working fine.

I verified by the command line:

`[david@vmkitchen-env ansible-test]# VBoxManage --version`

And it returned the correct value:

`5.2.8r121009`

Comment: hey davide, do you know what version of kernel-devel worked for you and how did you install it? i'm on a newer version or kernel-devel than virtualbox 6 is expecting and it seems to not recognize that the tool is installed.

Comment: Hi @yvanscher, 
I worked in a VM on my workstation. If I managed to find the correct VM (and I strongly think I did) the OS is CentOS 7, kernel version: 3.10.0_693.5.2.el7.x86_64.
I hope this might be of any benefits to solve your problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Below steps fixed the issue for me.

1.sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the Linux kernel "header" files matching the current kernel
for adding new hardware support to the system.
The distribution packages containing the headers are probably:
    kernel-devel kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
```

2.This website has the kernel module - [website](https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/updates/x86_64/repoview/kernel-devel.html)

wget https://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/centos/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64.rpm

4.yum localinstall kernel-devel-3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64.rpm -y

5.sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

Issue resolved

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora 36, I only had to run

`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`